# I'm trying to save the number received by executing the command to a file

Tags: bash, bash-completion

The output to the terminal is correct, but it saves an empty line to the file.

```
echo -n "Enter secret: "
read secret
echo $(/opt/homebrew/bin/oathtool --totp -b $secret)

$(/opt/homebrew/bin/oathtool --totp -b $secret) >> ./log
```

Answer (score 1):

Try either of the below:

```
echo $(/opt/homebrew/bin/oathtool --totp -b $secret) >> ./log
```

Or

```
/opt/homebrew/bin/oathtool --totp -b $secret >> ./log
```

In the first case, you have enclosed it within a `$()` which is known as the command substitution. It just basically returns the output from your command hence you need to echo it.